# Type synonyms in classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Lets say I've got a class like so:

```
class C a where
  type T a
```

I want to add a synonym inside the class like so:

```
class C a where
  type MT a
  type M = MT a
```

So I can just refer to `M` instead of `MT a`

I know this sounds like not a big deal, but say if I have something like this:

```
class Monad (MT a) => C a where
  type MT a
  type ItemT a
  new :: (MT a) a
  anotherSillyFunction :: [ItemT a] -> (MT a) a
  -- etc
```

But this approach makes the function definitions cleaner:

```
class Monad (MT a) => C a where
  type MT a
  type ItemT a
  type M = MT a
  type Item = ItemT a
  new :: M a
  anotherSillyFunction :: [Item] -> M a
  -- etc
```

Except the above doesn't compile. Anyway to achieve the above?

Comment: I can't see how this would work. I guess `M` is also visible from outside the class. When `M` is used, how could the compiler infer which instance it refers to, i.e. which `a` to use? If `M` was only visible inside the class (and possibly its instances?), perhaps it could work -- it would be better to use a different syntax for that, though, since we need to distinguish externally-visible type families from internal type synonyms.

Comment: Type, type synonym, and type family declarations in Haskell are always global. I doubt it would be easy to change that; that would seem tantamount to first-class modules.

Comment: I don't know if this would help, since you'd have to add it to every function you want to use it in, but if it is a very long type (especially if it's also used over and over in the type signature) it *could* help to do something like `anotherSillyFunction :: (item ~ ItemT a, m ~ MT a) => [item] -> m a`.